# Ember Route model AdapterPopulatedRecordArray vs RecordArray

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Could anyone give a hint on the inner workings of ember/ember-data:

In the route model function if I query comments with contract.id values an AdapterPopulatedRecordArray object is returned with the objects.

Route returns AdapterPopulatedRecordArray:

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('comment', { contract: 1 });
},
```

But if I don't query the comments a RecordArray object is returned with the objects.

Route returns RecordArray:

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('comment');
},
```

The crucial difference is that the RecordArray type live updates changes to the template and the AdapterPopulatedRecordArray doesn't and is immutable. My goal would be to make the objects from the first query live update and mutable.

I'm using with Ember 1.2/1.1.2 and latest-canary/beta3 Ember Data with Django Rest Framework Ember-data Adapter. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Yes you are right. But you could always modify response in AdapterPopulatedRecordArray. Instead of returning this array immediately in the model, process it in whatever form you like and then return.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how [Store#find works](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L284), `this.store.find('comment', { contract: 1 })` will call Store#findQuery.

The [docs for #findQuery](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L598) says

> This method returns a promise, which is resolved with a `RecordArray` once the server returns.

```
// #_findQuery
return resolve(promise).then(function(payload) {
  payload = serializer.extract(store, type, payload, null, 'findAll');
  // ...
  recordArray.load(payload);
  return recordArray;
```

Once [DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray#load](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/record_arrays/adapter_populated_record_array.js#L22) is called, the content property is set and should act like a RecordArray

```
this.setProperties({
  content: Ember.A(records),
  isLoaded: true,
  meta: meta
});
```

Are you not getting a server response yet when you're looking at `this.store.find('comment', { contract: 1 })`?

Comment: From what I gather he is getting a response but it is not live updating any further records.